# ctypes reference double pointer

Tags: python, ctypes

I have a C function that the doxygen looks like this:

```
long function( classA * obj1,
               classB * obj2,
               classC ** obj3,
               long value,
               const char * name1,
               const char * name2,
               classD ** obj4,
               classD ** obj5,
               classD ** obj6 
               )
```

I need to call it from python and get the 3 last arguments to pass to another dll. Currently I can call the DLL fine, but if I try to pass the last 3 arguments to the other function I get an error like this:

```
WindowsError: exception: access violation writing 0x0000000000000000
```

I am probably doing something wrong in the ctypes side of things and I would appreciate some light on how to use it...

The second DLL looks like this:

```
int function2(ClassD *  obj4)
```

And currently I "assemble" the last 3 arguments like this:

```
  temp=ctypes.c_long*1
  obj = temp(0)
```

Also, is there any way of going from ctypes to swig? Apparently I can do the other way around using the long function.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I had to do some extra digging to figure out how C-types works and the following seems to work. For function I needed to create an array:

```
arg = (ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_double) * 1)()
```

and pass it by reference to the function:

```
ctypes.byref(arg)
```

For the second function I would just pass one element of the array I created:

```
arg[0]
```

Comment: wow, you came back 2 months later and answered your question!  kudos and thanks