# convert mmap to ctypes void ** in python (swig)

Tags: python, ctypes, swig, mmap, void-pointers

I have used swig to generate a wrapper of a library in C.

I need to replicate a code in C in python, but I don't know how to go from mmap to void **

in C:

```
char *image_buf;
...
axidma_fd = open("/dev/axidma", O_RDWR|O_EXCL);
...
image_buf = mmap(NULL, image_byte_size, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE,
                      MAP_SHARED, axidma_fd, 0);
...
trans.num_frame_buffers = 1;
trans.frame_buffers = (void **)&image_buf;
```

in python

```
axidma_fd = os.open("/dev/axidma", os.O_RDWR|os.O_EXCL)
...
image_buf_1 = mmap.mmap(vdma_fd,188, mmap.MAP_SHARED,mmap.ACCESS_WRITE| mmap.ACCESS_READ);
...
# Convert mmap to c_char 
char_pointer = c_char.from_buffer(image_buf_1) ???? (but type is c_char not pointer)
# Double void
trans.frame_buffers = ??
```

***How do I convert an mmap to a pointer?***

***How do I get the double pointer?***

Would it be more efficient to do it in python directly or by instantiating the libc library?
for example like this

```
libc = ctypes.CDLL("libc.so.6")
image_mmap = ctypes.c_void_p(libc.mmap(0,188,mmap.ACCESS_WRITE| mmap.ACCESS_READ,mmap.MAP_SHARED,vdma_fd)
```

Thank you so much

**EDITED 1**
It explains me a little badly

if I do:

```
image_buf_1 = mmap.mmap(vdma_fd,188, mmap.MAP_SHARED,mmap.ACCESS_WRITE| mmap.ACCESS_READ)
image_map = c_void_p.from_buffer(image_buf_1)
```

image_map is None

```
>>> image_map
c_void_p(None)
```

On the other hand if I do

```
libc = ctypes.CDLL("libc.so.6")
image_mmap = ctypes.c_void_p(libc.mmap(0,188,mmap.ACCESS_WRITE| mmap.ACCESS_READ,mmap.MAP_SHARED,vdma_fd))
```

image_mmap is a valid pointer.

```
>>> image_mmap
c_void_p(18446744073709551615)
```

But when trying to assign it to

```
trans.frame_buffers = image_mmap
```

report:

```
trans.frame_buffers=image_mmap
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: in method 'axidma_video_transaction_frame_buffers_set', argument 2 of type 'void **'
```

I need convert mmap to void **

**EDITED 2**

Not working :(

I have defined:

```
class struct_axidma_video_transaction(Structure):
    pass

struct_axidma_video_transaction.__slots__ = [
    'channel_id',
    'num_frame_buffers',
    'frame_buffers',
    'frame',
]
struct_axidma_video_transaction._fields_ = [
    ('channel_id', c_int),
    ('num_frame_buffers', c_int),
    ('frame_buffers', POINTER(POINTER(None))),
    ('frame', struct_axidma_video_frame),
]
```

I need to convert a mmap to a POINTER(POINTER to pass it to the frame_buffers parameter:

```
>>> from ctypes import c_int, c_void_p, byref, CDLL, POINTER,c_int64
>>> import mmap
>>> vdma_fd = os.open("/dev/axidma",os.O_RDWR|os.O_EXCL)
>>> type(vdma_fd)
<class 'int'>
>>> vdma_buf    = mmap.mmap (vdma_fd,188,mmap.MAP_SHARED, mmap.ACCESS_READ | mmap.ACCESS_WRITE)
>>> type(vdma_buf)
<class 'mmap.mmap'>
>>> image_buf_p = c_void_p.from_buffer(vdma_buf)
>>> type(image_buf_p)
<class 'ctypes.c_void_p'>
>>> image_buf_pp = byref(image_buf_p)
>>> type(image_buf_pp)
<class 'CArgObject'>
>>> trans.frame_buffers = image_buf_pp
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: expected LP_c_void_p instance, got CArgObject
```

If I define:

```
>>> image_buf_pp = c_void_p.from_buffer(image_buf_p)
>>> type(image_buf_pp)
<class 'ctypes.c_void_p'>
>>> trans.frame_buffers = image_buf_pp
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: incompatible types, c_void_p instance instead of LP_c_void_p instance
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

Listing [[Python.Docs]: mmap - Memory-mapped file support](https://docs.python.org/3/library/mmap.html#module-mmap).

Check [[SO]: C function called from Python via ctypes returns incorrect value (@CristiFati's answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58611011/4788546) when working with *CTypes*.

Working with double (or multiple) pointers (that store array like data - like images are) is a bit tricky in *CTypes* (as seen in [[SO]: C++ & Python: Pass and return a 2D double pointer array from python to c++ (@CristiFati's answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58262388/4788546)).

Below is an example that uses arrays.

*code00.py*:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python

import ctypes as ct
import mmap
import os
import sys


#CharPtrPtr = ct.POINTER(ct.POINTER(ct.c_char))


def main(*argv):
    h = 3
    w = 4
    fname = "file.txt"
    with open(fname, mode="wb") as f:
        f.write(b"\x00" * h * w)
    fd = os.open(fname, os.O_RDWR | os.O_CREAT)
    buf = mmap.mmap(fd, h * w, mmap.MAP_SHARED, mmap.ACCESS_WRITE | mmap.ACCESS_READ)
    CharArrArr = ct.c_char * w * h
    img = CharArrArr.from_buffer(buf)
    for i in range(h):
        for j in range(w):
            img[i][j] = 0x41 + 2 * i * w + j
    del img
    buf.close()
    os.close(fd)
    with open(fname) as f:
        print("File contents:", f.read())


if __name__ == "__main__":
    print("Python {:s} {:03d}bit on {:s}\n".format(" ".join(elem.strip() for elem in sys.version.split("\n")),
                                                   64 if sys.maxsize > 0x100000000 else 32, sys.platform))
    rc = main(*sys.argv[1:])
    print("\nDone.")
    sys.exit(rc)
```

**Output**:

> ```
> (qaic-env) [cfati@cfati-5510-0:/mnt/e/Work/Dev/StackOverflow/q073614606]> python ./code00.py
> Python 3.8.10 (default, Jun 22 2022, 20:18:18) [GCC 9.4.0] 064bit on linux
>
> File contents: ABCDIJKLQRST
>
> Done.
> ```

Looking at the edit, it seems that I didn't get it right. Why do you need the *void*** pointer? What are you doing with it (what is *trans*)? Please share the code, not just scattered snippets.

If i got things right you need to get *mmap*'s return value (as *void**), and pass its address (which is a *void***) further. You can do it (using snippets from your code):

```py
image_buf_1 = mmap.mmap(vdma_fd, 188, mmap.MAP_SHARED, mmap.ACCESS_WRITE | mmap.ACCESS_READ)
image_map = ctypes.c_void_p.from_buffer(image_buf_1)
trans.frame_buffers = ctypes.pointer(image_mmap)
```

The other problem (*NULL* pointer): You're passing ***fd*** *0* (which is *StdIn*) to *libc.mmap* (also check 2<sup>nd</sup> *URL* for your hidden bug), while for *mmap.mmap* you're using the "real" descriptor, So I assume for that descriptor, memory couldn't be properly mapped (you should check *mmap* results in both cases (*image_buf_1*)).

Comment: I tried your solution and it doesn't work :(
see edited 2.

Comment: Use `image_buf_pp = pointer(image_buf_p)` (instead of *byref*). I missed that. But you also didn't pay attention to details. It's ***\_\_fields\_\_***.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks in part to this answer: [ctypes reference double pointer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12906552/ctypes-reference-double-pointer)

try `ctypes.byref()`. Sample code:

```
import ctypes
import mmap
import os

FILENAME=#<your filename>
FILELENGTH=#<your file's length>

fd = os.open(FILENAME, os.O_RDWR|os.O_EXCL)
image_buf_1 = mmap.mmap(fd, FILELENGTH, mmap.MAP_SHARED|mmap.ACCESS_WRITE|mmap.ACCESS_READ)

image_map = ctypes.c_void_p.from_buffer(image_buf_1)
print(f"{image_map.value:x}")
print(f"{ctypes.byref(image_map)}")      # this is the pointer you're looking for

os.system(f'cat /proc/$PPID/maps | grep {FILENAME}')    # verify the pointer value

os.close(fd)
```

Sorry, I don't know exactly what you mean by "the double pointer"; mmap returns a void*, represented here by ctypes.byref(image_map).

As for what's more efficient, you can of course profile, but usually your investment comes from doing the I/O rather than setting up the I/O (I'm assuming that ctypes.DLL is implemented via dlopen() which is pretty lightweight for an already-loaded library). Unless you're opening a very large number of files, I'd guess you want to choose your method based on whether you want to use the data in Python (you may need the Python mmap object) or not.

--note: I briefly tried the libc method you cited, but mmap returned -1, Invalid argument. I didn't look into what I was doing wrong there.